# getting errror in library itself twisted 21.7.0

Tags: ubuntu, twisted

```
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:         Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 85, in callWithContext
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 83, in callWithContext
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             return func(*args, **kw)
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 686, in _doReadOrWrite
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             why = selectable.doRead()
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:         --- <exception caught here> ---
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1406, in doRead
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             transport = self.transport(
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 809, in __init__
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             self.startReading()
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 437, in startReading
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             self.reactor.addReader(self)
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 117, in addReader
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             self._add(
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 103, in _add
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:             self._poller.modify(fd, flags)
Sep 27 09:25:00 ip-172-31-36-82 python3[28020]:         builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

getting this error from twisted 21.7.0 sometimes. is this known bug? i just running intermediate websocket server. no error in the main script as the traceback seems from library .

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A self-contained, complete example that demonstrates the problem would be of great help to anyone trying to answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.